# Read asp.net Page Import Directive at runtime

Tags: asp.net

Is there any way to read the asp.net Import directives at runtime? I have an ExpressionBuilder that is passed a number of class names. Right now I have to fully qulify these names but if I could read the namespaces from within the ExpressionBuilder, I can save myself a lot of typeing...

```
<%@ Import namespace="MyNameSpace.Data.Library" %>
```

//
//

```
string GetNamespace()
{
    return Page.blablabla(); // MyNameSpace.Data.Library
}
```

a bit more info:

I am using System.Web.BuildManager.GetType() to get the type of my object. When does (or can it) somehow reference the Import directives?

Comment: Can you list where you are feeding these classnames?  Also, without fully qualified class names, how are you sure they would be unique?  A bit more info on this would be helpful.

Comment: I have some classes within "support" libraries from which I need to read property values in an Expression Builder. Mainly looking for some maxlength values for data binding that I have exposed in my DAL library. I can't be sure that they are unique but I am happy to deal that that issue if needed. Some of the library names that I am referencing are very long. That might be another issue but not sure I have control over those names. Using the fully qualified names results in very long names in markup. I was hoping to reduce them by supplying some namespaces via the import directive.

Comment: Might add that Microsoft seems to be doing just this with some of their Data Source controls. You can specify just the class name for your data context in a LinqDataSource. I am using the BuildManager to instanciate my class and was hoping that somehow I could gain access to the namespaces or the BuildManager would do that for me. Somehow MS is doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching the subject, I don't think this can be done. You have to fully qualify your controls if the page does not import the namespace explcitly or implicitly (via the web.config).

In addition, I believe namespaces are not a "property" of a class.  I believe the compiler will just use them at compile time for checking and then will actually fully qualify the controls/classes when it compiles.  In other words, compiled code does not have a distinct list of "using or import" statements to evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

If you register the namespaces in the [namespaces section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164642.aspx) of `Web.config` instead of with `<%@ Import %>` statements, you can rather easily read them programmatically like this:

```
PagesSection pages = (PagesSection)
  ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/pages");

foreach (NamespaceInfo nsInfo in pages.Namespaces)
{
  string ns = nsInfo.Namespace;
  Response.Write(String.Format("<p>{0}</p>", ns));
}
```

If this is not an option, it should be rather easy to just wade through the markup of the `.aspx` files with some regular expressions.

Comment: I have access to the Page object but not sure I can get to the source. Even more sure I don't want to be doing that from deep down the DLL tree.

Have thought about adding the namespaces to the web.config file before and know how to access that but again, not ideal for my needs. Thanks but not really the answer I am looking for. +1 though!

Comment: You can get the source of the page by mapping the requested URI to the physical file responding to the request, then reading it through `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path)`. How to map the URI to the physical path depends on your URI scheme; whether it's rewritten, route-mapped with `System.Web.Routing`, or what.